# Data structures for ordering noisy data

Tags: data-structures, randomized-algorithms, permutations

In a certain robotics application, I encountered a problem in which we need to determine the order of positions of several robots on $\mathbb{R}$. Each measurement that we take of robot positions is subject to random errors beyond our control. I've formalised the algorithmic part of the problem as follows. This part has been reformulated as per D.W.'s comments.

The positions of $n$ robots are given to us in a $3\times n$ array, each row being of the form $[i, A, \epsilon]$.This row states   that the position of the robot with id $i$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $A \pm \epsilon$.

**Problem** : Output the most probable ordering (MPO) of the robot positions,
or one such if this is non-unique.

**Example** Input: 
$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm{id} & A & \epsilon \\ \hline  1 & 1& 0.5 \\ 2& 1.5 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Associate the two robot positions with random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Note that the pair $(X_1,X_2)$ is uniform on the rectangle $[0.5,1.5] \times [-0.5,3.5]$.  The probability $p_1$ (resp. $p_2$) that $X_1\leq X_2$ (resp. $X_1 \geq X_2$) is the area of this rectangle below (resp. above) the line $x_1\leq x_2$. If $p_1 \leq p_2$, then the MPO is $[1,2]$ , else $[2,1]$.

> What data structure efficiently computes the MPO?

I'm most interested in the range $n\in [10,1000]$.

**Simple idea that doesn't work** (thanks to D.W.): When $n\geq 3$, the MPO isn't equal to the sorted order of the means $A_i$. For example, the input $(1, 0.4\pm0), (2,0.5\pm 0.5), (3,0.7 \pm 0)$ has the MPO $[2,1,3]$ and not $[1,2,3]$ as the $A$'s would have us think.

One possible approach uses the [Sweep Line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm). Think of a robot position as a rectangle corresponding to its uniform pdf. Compute all intersecting rectangles using the Priority Queue of the sweep line, and reorder them as per the probability calculation above. (It may be possible to reduce the $O(n^2)$ pairwise comparison of probabilities to $O(n \log n)$; I haven't checked this though.) Non-overlapping rectangles leave their ordering intact.

Intuitively, large error bounds lead to long rectangles and potentially more overlaps, consequently increasing the running time. Likewise, small error bounds cause few overlaps, speeding up computations. This fact will be reflected in the sweep line.

Comment: I think $A_1 < A_2 \iff P( X_1< X_2 ) > 0.5 $

Comment: I am not sure that I have understood the question completely, but [Approximate Point-In-Triangle Test](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~tianhe/Papers/APIT_MobiCom03.pdf), which is a popular range-free localization method might be a starting point for you.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the natural ordering by the $A_i$s (i.e.: ignoring the error terms) is not the MPO?

Comment: A uniform distribution seems unlikely to be a reasonable model, based on what (little) I know about sensors.

Comment: @mhum, Here's an example for you.  Suppose robot 1 is at $0.4 \pm 0$, robot 2 is at $0.5 \pm 0.5$, and robot 3 is at $0.7 \pm 0$ (following the notation in the post for expressing a uniform distribution).  Then sorting by the $A_i$'s gives the order 123, but the MPO is 213 (in the most probable order, robot 2 is before robot 1).  As KWillets comment indicates, this kind of issue only arises once you have $\ge 3$ robots.

Comment: @Raphael, indeed, this is an unreasonable model of noise. I proposed a uniform model only for simplicity. In reality, the noise models are Gaussians, and computations become much harder.

Comment: @D.W Thanks for the example. I could not get time to reply to mhum earlier. Shall I include your example in the post?

Comment: @PKG, sure, feel free.  That's a good idea: it might help build intuition.  Follow-up question: How large is $n$, in your practical application?  I'm trying to get a feel for whether an exponential-time algorithm might be acceptable.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for the example. In fact, we can amplify that example further (by adding lots more robots with zero error in appropriate locations) so that the MPO has the $0.5 \pm 0.5$ robot in position 1 even though the overall probability of it being in that position is tiny, somewhat reminiscent of an Arrow's Impossibilty Theorem style result.